# Flask + WTForms - Display Fields in FormList

Tags: flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to build a form with dynamic fields (click a plus to add extra fields).

**forms.py**:

```
class ActionForm(Form):
    key = SelectField("Type: ", coerce=int, choices=[(0, "Option 1"), (1, "Option 2"), (2, "Opeion 3")], default=0)
    value = StringField('Value: ')


class EditForm(Form):
    content = StringField("Content: ")
    actions = FieldList(FormField(ActionForm))
    status = RadioField("Status: ", coerce=int, choices=[(0, "Inactive"), (1, "Active")], default=1)
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

**View Template (Won't Render the Fields from ActionForm):**

```
<form method="POST">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ form.actions.label }}
<div class="form-group input-group">
    {% for action in form.actions %}
        {% for field in action %}
            {{ field() }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{{ form.status.label }}{{ form.status }}
{{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

Problem:

In my form, I just see a blank spot where the `ActionForm` fields should appear.

In other words, I can't iterate through `form.actions` (to show the SelectField() and StringField()).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where do you have the render() command?

Comment: @AndrewKloos: It's in my view function. I'm able to get the form to display (the status appears, for example), but the `FieldList`ed fields don't. I'm basically just trying to support this Bootstrap Multiple Field element: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multiple-fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FieldList`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList) takes a `min_entries` keyword argument - if you set it, it will ensure that there are at least `n` entries:

```
class EditForm(Form):
    content = StringField("Content: ")
    actions = FieldList(FormField(ActionForm), min_entries=1)
```